# Failure to import plot_helper in CobraPy

Tags: python, python-import, toolkit, cobra

I am trying to do [this tutorial](https://cobrapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/loopless.html#Method) for CobraPy and can't seem to get plot_helper to import

Where is plot_helper? Is it a pip download?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. I am new to cobrapy, but this solved my problem. 
I used the following link for the scatter plot
https://python-graph-gallery.com/130-basic-matplotlib-scatterplot/
So in Section 8.1 the additional changes I personally used are:

I replaced `import plot_helper` in In[1] with:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot
```

Instead of In[4] I used:

```
matplotlib.pyplot.plot("loopless", "nominal", data=df, linestyle='none', marker='o')
matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```

Hope this helps